# Flutter Firebase - DropdownMenuItem: The method 'map' was called on null

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, dart

In my application I would like to display vaccines according to the species of the animal (If is a dog or cat). I'm experiencing an error: *The method 'map' was called on null. Tried calling: map DropdownMenuItem*. Why is this happening? I already put async and await in the methods, I don't understand why it is still null. Bellow my code:

1) This is where I call my DropdownContent class in init to prepare my DropdownMenuItem in the row inside the widget

```
class _VaccineDetailFormState extends State<VaccineDetailForm> {

final DataRepository repository = DataRepository();
String selectedVaccine = "Select";
List<String> vaccinesBySpecie;

  initState() {
    DropdownContent.getVaccines(widget.selectedPetID).then((value) => vaccinesBySpecie = value);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    [...]
              new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new DropdownButton<String>(
                      value:  widget.vaccine.name == null ? selectedVaccine: widget.vaccine.name,
                      underline: Container(
                        height: 2,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                      onChanged: (String newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedVaccine = newValue;
                          widget.vaccine.name = newValue;
                        });
                      },
                      items: vaccinesBySpecie.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: value,
                          child: Text(value),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    )
                  ]),

                  [...]
```

2) Here is the DropdownContent class that, inside the getVaccines() method, searches the repository to find out the species of the current animal and then returns the appropriate vaccine list.

```
class Dropdown content

static Future<List<String>> getVaccines(String petId) async {

    final DataRepository repository = DataRepository();
    String currentSpecie = await repository.getSpecie(petId);

    if (currentSpecie.contains('Dog')) {
      return listOfVaccinesForDogs();
    }
    if (currentSpecie.contains('Cat')) {
      return listOfVaccinesForCats();
    }
}
```

3) Finally, the repository class that searches for the species of the animal

```
 class Repository

   Future<String> getSpecie(String petId) async {
    DocumentReference documentReference = petCollection.document(petId);
    await documentReference.get().then((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.data['specie'].toString();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Dean said illuminated my ideas. I managed to solve it by reaching the following answer:

1) DropdownMenuItem inside the widget

```
 Container(
                child:  FutureBuilder <List<String>>(
                    future: DropdownContent.getVaccines(widget.selectedPetID),
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if(snapshot.data == null) {
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }
                      else {
                        return DropdownButton<String>(
                          value: widget.vaccine.name == null? selectedVaccine: widget.vaccine.name,
                          underline: Container(
                            height: 2,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          onChanged: (String newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedVaccine = newValue;
                              widget.vaccine.name = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: snapshot.data.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((value) =>
                          new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            child: Text(value),
                            value: value,
                          ))
                              .toList(),
                        );
                      }
                    })
              )
```

2) DropdownContent class that searches the repository to find out the species of the current animal and then returns the appropriate vaccine list:

```
  static Future<List<String>> getVaccines(String petId) async {
    final DataRepository repository = DataRepository();
    String currentSpecie;
    await repository.getSpecie(petId).then((value) {
      currentSpecie = value;
    });

    if (currentSpecie.contains('Dog')) {
      return listOfVaccinesForDogs();
    }
    if (currentSpecie.contains('Cat')) {
      return listOfVaccinesForCats();
    }
  }
```

3) The repository class that searches for the species of the animal

```
  Future<String> getSpecie(String petId) async {
    DocumentReference documentReference = petCollection.document(petId);
    String specie;
    await documentReference.get().then((snapshot) {
      specie = snapshot.data['specie'].toString();
    });
    return specie;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

While your initState method may be asynchronous, your build method isn't. So at the time that the build method is called, your vaccinesBySpecie method is null. 
The best way to fix this would be to initialize your `List<String> vaccinesBySpecie` like so `List<String> vaccinesBySpecie = [];`. This way it isn't null when the build method is called.

As a side note, I would suggest using a FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder if you can, that way you can handle when there isn't a value (i.e it is null) vs when there is a value(ie it is not null)

Comment: Hi. I initialized as you suggested. The error "map was called on null" was gone but the dropdown is empty, I thought it was because the FutureBuilder you said so I tried adding this but now I'm back to the same error.